# How to release a file after accessing it with JavaScript (adobe)

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am writing some javascript to update pdf fields from a text file.  Finally got it working.  But now I find that I am unable to update that text file until I close out all pdf forms.  I am getting the error:

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

The code I am using:

```
  //Grab the current path and update it to indicate the TempInfo location
  var strPath = this.path;
  strPath = strPath.slice(0,-12);
  strPath = strPath + "TempInfo.txt"

  //Get data from TempFile into array, display message if no file found
  try{
    var dataStream = util.readFileIntoStream(strPath);
    var dataFrom = util.stringFromStream(dataStream);
  }catch(e){
  app.alert("Temp file not found");
  }

  //Put the data into an array and update the field
  var strTest = new Array();
  strTest = dataFrom.split(/\n/);

  getField("Username").value = strTest[0];
```

Is there a way to release the file after using the "util" commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the reference to the file. Add the line below to the end of your code.

```
dataStream = null;
```